# Isolate "a" in a quadratic function

Tags: quadratics

You have a quadratic function: $ax^2 + bx + c = y$. If you know $b$ and $c$, are able to plug any domain value $x$ into this blackbox equation and receive a range value $y$, and do not know the vertex of the equation, how could you find the unknown variable $a$.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. So you're saying you know the values of $b$, $c$, and $f(x)$ for some $x$? And with these, you want to find $a$?

Comment: Do you mean $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, or is there a $y$ variable?

Comment: If I read this correctly, if you know $b$ and $c$ and if you can plug in any value of $x$ and receive the corresponding value of $y$, then it really becomes a problem with one unknown, namely $a$.

Comment: The solution for $a$ is $\dfrac{y-bx-c}{x^2}$, if that's what you want.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar : You should post as an answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! I have edited your question a bit - please check if these edits are OK. As to you question" If you can plug in $x$ on the left hand side and are told $y$ on the right hans side, you can set up a single equation for the unknown $a$ and solve for it. Try it with $b = 2, c = 3, x = -2, y = 1$. What is the equation you will get for $a$ and what is the solution? And what is the general process?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I will try that thanks. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @HansEngler thanks thats great, and thank you for the welcome!

Comment: @dmk yes I'm looking for a using values b, c, x, and y.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar thank you! So far it seems to work. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @PaulT.: What do you mean by "so far it seems to work"? Either you understand why it works and can convince someone else that it does, or you don't and shouldn't rely on 'experience' to confirm correctness. You must verify it yourself. Try $x=0$ in his formula and see if it works! To get the answer yourself, substitute $x=1$ into your blackbox and see what you are supposed to get.

Comment: @user21820 I works except the equation x cannot equal zero for obvious reasons.

Comment: @PaulT.: Yes, but do you understand it completely and can you get the answer on your own? The answer itself is unimportant, but knowing why it is the answer is important.

Comment: @user21820 I believe I do a thought process showing how the equation was derived would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for $a$ is 
$$a=\begin{cases}\dfrac{y-bx-c}{x^2} & x\neq0\\
\text{unknown value} & x=0\end{cases}$$
How that is derived can be seen by rearranging and dividing.

Comment: Not right. All you can say is that $a$ is unknown, not arbitrary.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Thanks for the response! It solved my problem.

Comment: @PaulT. Sure!${}{}{}$